# AnimationPlayer animations do not play in Godot

Tags: c#, godot

## Forewords

Firstly, I know posting graphical resources for codes is not encouraged in this platform. I will also post the code but, in this particular case, I think posting a video about it is much more helpful than just posting some arbitrary code because the structuring of game projects really vary depending on their requirements. However, I still respect the platform's rules so if a mod asks me to format my question according to the community rules, I can do that or they also can simply delete my question. I respect that.

## The Issue

It's actually a simple issue but it's driving me crazy because of its simplicity. I just want to fade in when I load a scene and then fade out whenever I click a button. As to how I do that, [this is the video about it](https://streamable.com/i4zz7v).

To sum up, I load another scene called "Fader" which contains a `ColorRect` with a black color and `AnimationPlayer` to change `ColorRect`'s alpha value.

The code is below with extra comments on relevant parts:

```cs
using Godot;
using System;

public class TitleScreen : Control
{
    private Button[] buttons;
    private Control fader;  // the scene that I inject

    public override void _Ready()  // when title screen gets ready
    {
        GD.Print("Preparing TitleScreen...");
        InitButtons();
        InitFader();  // initialize fader
        FadeIn();  // do fade in animation
    }

    private void InitFader()  // initializing fader
    {
        GD.Print("Initializing fader...");
        var faderScene = (PackedScene)ResourceLoader.Load("res://components/Fader.tscn");  // load external fader scene
        fader = (Control)faderScene.Instance();  // instantiate the scene
        fader.SetSize(OS.WindowSize);  // set the size of fader scene to the game window, just in case
        var rect = (ColorRect)fader.GetNode("rect");  // get "rect" child from fader scene
        rect.SetSize(OS.WindowSize);  // set "rect" size to the game window as well, just in case
        fader.Visible = false;  // set the visibility to false
        AddChild(fader);  // add initialized fader scene as a child of title screen
    }

    private void InitButtons()
    {
        GD.Print("Initializing buttons...");
        buttons = new Button[3]{
            (Button)GetNode("menu_container/leftmenu_container/menu/start_button"),
            (Button)GetNode("menu_container/leftmenu_container/menu/continue_button"),
            (Button)GetNode("menu_container/leftmenu_container/menu/exit_button"),
        };

        GD.Print("Adding events to buttons...");
        buttons[0].Connect("pressed", this, "_StartGame");
        buttons[2].Connect("pressed", this, "_QuitGame");
    }

    private void FadeIn()
    {
        GD.Print("Fading in...");
        fader.Visible = true;  // set visibility of fader to true
        var player = (AnimationPlayer)fader.GetNode("player");  // get animation player
        player.Play("FadeIn");  // play FadeIn animation
        fader.Visible = false;  // set visibility of fader to false
    }

    private void FadeOut()
    {
        // similar to FadeIn
        GD.Print("Fading out...");
        fader.Visible = true;
        var player = (AnimationPlayer)fader.GetNode("player");
        player.Play("FadeOut");
        fader.Visible = false;
    }

    public void _StartGame()  // whenever I click start game button
    {
        FadeOut();  // fade out
        GetTree().ChangeScene("res://stages/Demo01.tscn");
    }

    public void _QuitGame()  // whenever I click quit game button
    {
        FadeOut();  // fade out
        GetTree().Quit();
    }
}
```

Seems like I can't see something. Why does it not fade in and out?

---

## Environment

- Manjaro 19.0.2
- Mono JIT Compiler 6.4.0 (if it is relevant)
- Godot 3.2

Comment: Comment out the `fader.Visible = false;` statements to get ahead, they hide the fader far too early.

Comment: @HansPassant | Yep, [that seems to be the issue](https://godotengine.org/qa/66658/animationplayer-animations-do-not-play-in-godot?show=66667#a66667). I half solved the issue using `animation_started` and `animation_finished` signals on `AnimationPlayer`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue was `Play` method on `AnimationPlayer` object *kinda* runs like async (dunno if this is the correct term for it).

Luckily, there is a feature called *signals* in Godot. There are `animation_started` and `animation_finished` signals on `AnimationPlayer` objects. Basically, I created a C# script for Fader scene, hooked the signals from `player` to `fader` as in:

- `animation_started` to `_FaderAnimationStart`
- `animation_finished` to `_FaderAnimationEnd`

At the end, my script looks like below:

```cs
using Godot;
using System;

public class Fader : Control
{
    private ColorRect rect;
    private AnimationPlayer player;

    public override void _Ready()
    {
        GD.Print("Initializing Fader...");

        rect = (ColorRect)GetNode("rect");
        player = (AnimationPlayer)GetNode("player");

        SetSize(OS.WindowSize);
        rect.SetSize(OS.WindowSize);

        Visible = false;
    }

    private void _FaderAnimationStart(String anim_name)
    {
        Visible = true;
    }

    private void _FaderAnimationEnd(String anim_name)
    {
        Visible = false;
    }
}
```

I solved it thanks to [njamster](https://godotengine.org/qa/user/njamster)'s [answer](https://godotengine.org/qa/66658/animationplayer-animations-do-not-play-in-godot?show=66667#a66667) and [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081448/animationplayer-animations-do-not-play-in-godot#comment108077045_61081448).

However, this only solves half of the problem. Yes, the scene now fades in when it loads but it does not fade out. Given that it executes kinda-async (again, I'm not sure if this is the correct term), changing scene interrupts while running the animation. <strike>I will update the answer when I solve that problem as well.</strike>

## Update

Well, I cannot seem to solve the fade out part because it requires to access parent node from initialized child scene. There are some methods I can think of.

First one is to *somehow* parameterize "Fader" scene. This can be done in many ways but at the end, when you initialize it from another scene, you need to cast it to `Fader` and I don't know if this is a valid way to do it. Another concern is standardizing this in the codebase. A similar method is discussed in [here](https://godotengine.org/qa/4786/how-to-pass-parameters-when-instantiating-a-node).

Second one is to [write it as a plugin](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/plugins/editor/making_plugins.html) which has it benefits and drawbacks. C# is not really battle-tested in this particular area.

Third one is to use a state management system. Here is a [redux](https://github.com/glumpyfish/godot_redux) implementation for Godot. And you need to somehow integrate it for signals, which seems like a hassle.

So, overall, I still do not know how to fade out.